# Redirect loop when using before_filter in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, admin

Hello guys so what i want to do is simple.

I want a before filter to check if the current user is admin, to automatically redirect him to the admin panel even if the admin accesses the index page(e.g localhost:3000 which is the root url for normal users)

for the admin users the path is localhost:3000/admin/

I have written these blocks of code so far but cause a redirect loop

in my application_controller.rb i have this

```
include SessionsHelper
before_filter :admin_users?


  private
    def admin_users?
      if current_user.admin?
        redirect_to admin_path
      end
    end
```

and the current_user method is the following which is in sessionshelper.rb

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

here is users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :admin_users? # application controller method

  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index,:edit,:update] # is in Application Controller
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit,:update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
    end

    # before filters


    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

any clues?

Comment: Where have you put your `before_filter`

Comment: as said in application_controller.rb

Comment: Your method name is `admin_user` not `admin_users?`

Comment: since in user controller i have already an admin_user method, i changed the one in application controller to admin_users? instead. but the naming doesnt seem to be the error. updated the post with correct names

Comment: set your `admin_users?` filter last, but before `admin_user` filter

Comment: done,nothing changed. no redirect happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83865/discussion-between-petros-kyriakou-and-nermin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is next. You have put your redirect inside `application_controller.rb`, that all other controller inherit from, even Admin controller.

You have to do next:

remove `before_filter :admin_user` from your `ApplicationController`, and put it only where you want to check if user is admin, all controllers except admin controller.

You have redirect loop because admin controller will redirect to admin_path, when you come to admin_path.

Comment: can i do something like before_filter :admin_user, except: [:admin_controller] ?

Comment: No, and it is not good practice to put `filters` inside `application_controller.rb` you can leave method declaration, but `before_filter` add to every controller you want to check if user is admin, it is better practice

Comment: I see.Well i've removed the filter from applicationcontroller and left just the method and i've added the filter to both users and session controller but now its not even causing a redirection for some reason. When i used the filter inside application controller it worked even though it caused a redirect loop.

Comment: added it just now to original post.